# Shell script to send email is not working from Informatica

Tags: linux, unix, informatica, informatica-powercenter, workflow-manager-1.x

I have a very simple script

```bash
echo "Test email body" | mailx -s "Subject" vinay@informatica.com
```

When I run the script from linux, it's working fine and I'm receiving the email

But, when I use the same script in post session success command or command task in informatica, the script is successful but I did not receive the mail

Also, without calling the script, I directly gave the mail command in post session success command

```bash
echo "Test email body" | mailx -s "Subject" vinay@informatica.com
```

Still, it's not working.

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: Does `echo` exist as a stand-alone binary in your system? `which echo` ...  If not, then that may well be your problem. Chances are that informatica **doesn't** execute shell-builtins, but I don't know informatica at all.  An option to test this would be to add the line above to a script, and rund the script from informatica.

Comment: I included  #!/usr/bin/sh above the echo statement
still no result

Comment: What do you mean by that? Did you put it all in a shell-script, set that to executable and ran it from there? It's also possible that informatica doesn't like shell features like pipes or redirects in the **command**.

Comment: Yes i tried that, I put the below commands in a shell script as well but still not working

Comment: Does it run any OTHER commands at all?

Comment: Can you not use infa mail task pls?

Comment: Even email task is not working....might be some configuration issue...can someone help me on the configuration settings for the same

Answer (score 0):

```
touch email.txt > you message
cat /tmp/email.txt 

Subject: Terminal Email Send

Email Content line 1
Email Content line 2
```

Comment: explonation:   sendmail user@example.com  < /tmp/email.txt

Comment: Can you please elaborate. You want me to copy the mail content into a file and subject in a variable??